# Recive a alert API in PHP POST web service

Tags: php, api, web-services

i used [flightstates](https://developer.flightstats.com/products) API  to create get an live flight status.
And they provide a alert messaging in their api. and they says "[To use the Alerts API, the developer must implement a web service that accepts an HTTP POST and parses an Alerts Message, then set up a rule specifying that service as the destination.](https://developer.flightstats.com/products/alerts)".
I create a web service like this:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
$que = mysqli_query($con,"insert into firetable (datas) values ('$data')");
```

but it store value "Array".
how  can store the data in database?

```
 "alert":{  
          "event":{  },
          "dataSource":"Airline",
          "dateTimeRecorded":"2017-12-05T08:36:24.957Z",
          "rule":{  },
          "flightStatus":{  
             "flightId":"942163187",
             "carrierFsCode":"9W",
             "flightNumber":"527",
             "departureAirportFsCode":"DXB",
             "arrivalAirportFsCode":"COK",
             "departureDate":{  
                "dateLocal":"2017-12-05T12:25:00.000",
                "dateUtc":"2017-12-05T08:25:00.000Z"
             },
             "arrivalDate":{  
                "dateLocal":"2017-12-05T17:50:00.000",
                "dateUtc":"2017-12-05T12:20:00.000Z"
             },...............
............................
```

API response like this(this response i get in my email,when i give mail email id as the service).
How i can store the 'flightId','flightNumber' etc to the database?

Comment: `$data=json_decode($data);`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// remove json_decode 
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
```

to

```
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');

$que = mysqli_query($con,"insert into firetable (datas) values ('$data')");
```

data will be stored in JSON format in DB.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can use json_decode function:

```
$obj = json_decode($json,true); // this is the string you are storing in the database
echo $obj['alert'][0]['flightStatus'][0]['flightId']; // here is 942163187
```

More information about the function:
[enter link description here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)